# Can't push all array items into a second array PHP

Tags: php

So I have an array `($items)` which has about 900 items in it. What I'm trying to do is, for the items that are read `($key["status"] == 1)` which is about 300 items -> push those into a second array `($lifeSpanArray)` with two attributes (`added_date` and `read_date`).

For some reason, when I try to push items into the lifespan array, I only have one item. Like I said, there are around 300 items that are status read - and I can dump those out, so I believe I am making a mistake with building my lifeSpanArray and pushing into it.

Any help much appreciated!

```
$items = $pocket->retrieve($params, $accessToken);
$numberArticles = count($items["list"]);
$hasRead = 0;
$hasNotRead = 0;

$readDatesArray = array();
$lifeSpanArray = array();


foreach ($items['list'] as $key) {

    if ($key["status"] == 1) {
        $hasRead++;
        $timeAdded = date('m/d/Y', $key["time_added"]); 
        $dateRead = date('m/d/Y', $key["time_read"]);

        // Where the problem is - only one item added
        $lifeSpanArray['timeAdded'] = $timeAdded;
        $lifeSpanArray['timeRead'] = $dateRead;

        //Push into the read dates array
        array_push($readDatesArray, $dateRead);

    }
    else {
        $hasNotRead++;
    }

}

var_dump($lifeSpanArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are overwriting your `$lifeSpanArray` array on each iteration you're must be getting only last entry so what you need is a two-dimension array,

Change this,

```
//Push into lifespan array
$lifeSpanArray['timeAdded'] = $timeAdded;
$lifeSpanArray['timeRead'] = $dateRead;
```

to,

```
 $lifeSpanArray[] = array('timeAdded' => $timeAdded,'timeRead' => $dateRead);
```

Comment: Ah, that is obvious, rewriting it each time. THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you provide us the `$lifeSpanArray` array you getting. Also I will recommended you to post a question for it.

Comment: Here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759729/get-average-interval-between-two-dates-php Thanks Rikesh, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$lifeSpanArray['timeAdded'] = $timeAdded;
$lifeSpanArray['timeRead'] = $dateRead;
```

For the above code, you are actually assigning a **[scalar value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php)** to `$lifeSpanArray['timeAdded']` and `$lifeSpanArray['timeRead']`.

To treat them as array and push values to them, you should first initialize timeAdded and timeRead as arrays first:

```
$lifeSpanArray = array(
    'timeAdded' => array(),
    'timeRead' => array()
);
```

And pushing values to them within the `foreach` loop:

```
$lifeSpanArray['timeAdded'][] = $timeAdded;
$lifeSpanArray['timeRead'][] = $dateRead;
```